# Can resurrected bodies have rights to the Iron Throne?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I think to remember some discussion telling that time ago, centuries ago, the noble houses of Westeros had agreed that a resurrected person has no more rights to any title of nobility.

I though this was canon in the books, but now I can not find any reference so perhaps it was just speculation in the forums. Can anybody remember some reference, canonical, related to this?

Comment: "Yes I have resurrected King Jaehaerys here with me, Get off your throne, it's his by rights. And no, that's not a string. Why, I have never watched Weekend at Bernie's"

Comment: Resurrected body are literally miracles, related to R'hllor, a religion that is more than minor in Westeros. The other case of resurrections are wights, but until very recently, this was considered as myths. Due to the absence of resurrection, I really don't see why noble would even consider what rights should a resurrected body should have

Comment: @Kepotx yeah, I see. Somehow I thought I had read about that. Perhaps I am confused with some other saga. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are possibly confused by Jon no longer considering himself a Night's Watchman because the oath starts:

> Night gathers, and now my watch begins. It shall not end until my death.

He died and so his watch ended.

Comment: This doesn't mean he cannot take the black again.

Answer (score -1):

The question is based in an erroneous transposition of worlds; the rule about resurrection is from comic "Girl Genius", a steampunk series.